# SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop, this is the error showing

Tags: python

```
command = ""
while True :
    command = input('>').lower()
if command =="start":
    print('Your Car have Started ')
elif command == "stop":
    print('Your Car have Stopped')
elif command == "help":
    print('''
Start- To Start the car.
Stop- To Stop the car.
Quit- To Exit.
''')
elif command == "quit":
   break
else:
    print("Hey I don't understand your command")
```

Comment: Please fix your formatting: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Your indenting is off: I assume the `if/elif/else` should be indented inside the `while`. Then the `break` will make sense.

Comment: Well the error pretty much talks for itself. You have a `break` statement that is outside any loop. Python is based on indentations so indentation levels define scopes. Your `break` should be indented to a loop's scope

Comment: hey what is loop's scope...got stuck here for a day

Answer (score 2):

break needs to be inside your loop, as the error says. You might have accidentally wrote it outside. Move the part below while by pressing tab.
Please check out the python [formatting guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) if it is unclear.

```
command = ""
while True :
    command = input('>').lower()
    if command =="start":
       print('Your Car have Started ')
    elif command == "stop":
       print('Your Car have Stopped')
    elif command == "help":
       print('''
          Start- To Start the car.
          Stop- To Stop the car.
          Quit- To Exit.
          ''')
   elif command == "quit":
       break
   else:
       print("Hey I don't understand your command")
```

Comment: Please improve the indenting. Indenting to PEP8 would be nice.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting , approved it